# UIAccessibility - When dismissing another view, set focus to previous accessibility element

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I am implementing accessibility into our current project and have some issues on setting focus on an element in a previous viewcontroller.

An example would be:

A user selects on a tableview cell at index 3.  In `didSelectRowAt`, we present to the user a `UIActionSheet` where the user makes a selection.  Once the user makes a selection and the presented `UIActionSheet` is dismissed, the accessibility focus SHOULD be selected at tableview cell index 3, but instead the focus is set back to the initial element in the view, in my case most top-left element.

I have used `UIAccessibility.Notification` `.screenChanged` and `UIView.accessibilityViewIsModal`to set a new focus when presenting a modal view, but this doesn't seem to have a good solution to point back to a previous element when dismissing a view.

Any insight on how to track the previous accessibility element focus would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a variable that will store the previous position in the `TableViewController`:

```
var previousPosition: IndexPath?
```

Then, store this position once you tap on a cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    previousPosition = indexPath
}
```

Finally, when the presented `UIActionSheet` is dismissed *(example of a back button hereafter)*, the following code snippet selects and focuses the table view cell from which the latest tap has been triggered:

```
var actionSheet: UIAlertController?

actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet",
                                message: "Ready to go back?",
                                preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let backButton = UIAlertAction(title: "B.A.C.K.",
                               style: .cancel,
                               handler: { (action) -> Void in

        print("Back button tapped")

        self.tableView.selectRow(at: self.previousPosition,
                                 animated: true,
                                 scrollPosition: .none)

       let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: self.previousPosition!)

       UIAccessibility.post(notification:.layoutChanged,
                            argument: currentCell)
})

actionSheet!.addAction(backButton)
```

Check out the result of this code snippet in a blank project and adapt it in your app to make it work as desired.

**EDIT**: besides my code snippet, take a look at the **[`remembersLastFocusedIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614858-rememberslastfocusedindexpath)** instance property of the table view that may provide the direct result in conjunction with the **[`restoresFocusAfterTransition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1829440-restoresfocusaftertransition)** instance property of the view controller.